# Difference between Divide and Conquer & Subtract and Conquer?

Tags: algorithm, recursion, divide-and-conquer

I have been reading about recursion and solving recurrence equations. Came across a term "subtract and conquer". How is it different from the "Divide and Conquer" technique?
Can I solve these kind of problems using the same techniques used for solving divide and conquer recurrence equations (like master theorem or recursion tree)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

"The master theorem applies to divide and conquer algorithms. Some algorithms lead to recurrences of the form T(n) = aT(n-b) + Θ(nd). These might be called "subtract and conquer" or "giant step, baby step" algorithms."

Actually subtract differs from divide, that size of sub problem not divided, but subtracting, everything else is the similar.

Check this link for more details http://www.eecis.udel.edu/~saunders/courses/621/11s/notes/notes/Master-theorem.html

Comment: How do we solve the "subtract and conquer" recurrence equations? can you please give an example for the same

Answer (score 1):

I read about "Divide and Conquer" algorithm and came across "Decrease and Conquer" which used Binary Search as its example.
So I think "Subtract and Conquer" relates to "Decrease and Conquer" where instead of joining the sub-problems to find the final solution, we find the solution from the sub-problem itself ignoring the remaining part of the original problem.

Answer (score 0):

Just adding on the great answer given by [Mysterion](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2663985) on this topic, as the resource link is broken, I had trouble finding good resources about Master Theorem related to Decrease and Conquer (also known as Substract and Conquer) algorithms but I came across [this document](https://www.eecis.udel.edu/%7Esaunders/notes/recurrence-relations.pdf) from UDel CS Program

[image]

Hope this helps someone else when searching about this.